# TypeORM update query using repository pattern, how to update a table with a where clause selection and update only one field

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have a barcode table with an `is_active` field. I want to update this boolean field when the user wants to deactivate this barcode.

in the barcode entity, it is called `isActive`.

[image]

I tried this query using repository pattern but it gives the following SQL query.

```
this.barcodeRepository
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .update(Barcode)
      .set({ isActive: true })
      .where('code = :codeToupdate', { codeToupdate: 'sfsdfdsf' })
      .getQuery();
```

the output SQL query is this.

```
UPDATE "barcode" SET "is_active" = :orm_param_0 WHERE "code" = :codeToupdate
```

I am not sure what causes it to output `:orm_param_0`.

Anyone please help with the proper typeorm update steps..

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
this.barcodeRepository
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .update({ isActive: true })
      .where('code = :codeToupdate', { codeToupdate: 'sfsdfdsf' })
      .getQuery();
```